# Sending SQL query in URL using NSURLRequest in ObjC

Tags: php, objective-c, sql, get, nsurlrequest

I have a very weird problem while trying to pass and SQL query using the NSURLRequest class in objective C. I am able to send a simple query that works and returns the right content (JSON formatted). 
Here is my code :

```
NSString *URLWithSQLQuery = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://localhost/querydatabase.php?query=INSERT+INTO+Table+(ID,Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8)+VALUES+(NULL,'a','b','','c','d','','1','2')"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLWithSQLQuery]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

This does not insert the dummy values into the table.
The following code returns the right content :

```
NSString *URLWithSQLQuery = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://localhost/querydatabase.php?query=SELECT+*+FROM+Table"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLWithSQLQuery]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

And when I paste the url [http://localhost/querydatabase.php?query=INSERT+INTO+Table+(ID,Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8)+VALUES+(NULL,'a','b','','c','d','','1','2')](http://localhost/querydatabase.php?query=INSERT%20INTO%20Table%20%28ID,Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8%29%20VALUES%20%28NULL,%27a%27,%27b%27,%27%27,%27c%27,%27d%27,%27%27,%271%27,%272%27%29) into my browser, the query is executed properly. So I really don't know where the problem comes from as it does not come from the PHP script or the `URLWithSQLQuery` nor does it come from my Objective C code.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all for your help.

Scott

Comment: Never mind, my URL string was a string with format and it used other strings which contained spaces I need to replace those with '+'. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I changed it and am now using POST method instead of the URL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question has been answered, but I think it's worth pointing something out to anyone who comes across this question in future, as well as the poster of the question:

## Don't EVER send actual SQL through your URLs

This is a **gigantic** security flaw. Without an utterly ridiculous amount of sanitisation and validation, this code, when unleashed into the wild, will leave your server and database wide open to exploit.

I'm going to make the assumption you shove the query string into `mysql_query()` or whatever, like:

```
$query = mysql_query($_GET['query']);
```

Anyone who finds your API doesn't even need to hack it, because you've done all the hard work for them. It's like building Fort Knox but leaving the front door open. The building can withstand an attack, but anyone who knows can just walk in.

They just need to change the URL to whatever query they like:

```
// Delete one of your databases
http://your-server.com/querydatabase.php?query=DROP+DATABASE+DBNAME

// Create a new user account to log in directly
http://your-server.com/querydatabase.php?query=GRANT+ALL+PRIVILEGES+ON+*.*+TO+'bobby'%40%25+IDENTIFIED+BY+'password'
```

Your PHP code needs to take a series of separate parameters for the data you want to save, and you need to make sure they're sane and valid before you insert them into a pre-built SQL query. This severely limits (but does not prevent all of) the opportunities available to an unscrupulous individual to do something bad with your server.

As a very basic example (in the style of what you already have):

```
// get records from the database
http://your-server.com/querydatabase.php?query=list

if ($_GET['query'] == 'list') {
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
}

// you would actually make a POST request to do this
http://your-server.com/querydatabase.php?query=save&column1=value1&column2=value2...

if ($_GET['query'] == 'save') {
    $column1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['column1']);
    $column2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['column2']);

   // only want column 1 to be an integer?
   if (!ctype_digit($column1)) die("Column 1 is not a number");

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (column1, column2) VALUES ($column1, $column2)");
}
```

The preferred and slightly more advanced method is to ditch `mysql_*` and use `mysqli` or `PDO` (or an ORM, which handles it all for you), so you can use [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

This may seem unimportant, especially since you're running it on localhost, but what is demonstrated in the question is **dangerous**.

Comment: +1 for the dont - that's why services exist - to abstract and secure your storage

Comment: Is sending a query through POST dangerous? I am only using this as a tool to fill in my database using my program, no more. The php page is not accessible from the Internet.
PS : I am using PDO

Comment: Sending a query over an HTTP request is dangerous no matter how you send it.